# Is the GEF really a MVC framework?

Tags: model-view-controller, eclipse-emf, eclipse-gef

in the tutorials from http://www.vainolo.com/tutorials/ the position of the model is saved in the model. I want to save all data to file and want to get the same view, when I load the file.

Searching for an answer for this question, I got another more important question:
**Is the GEF really a MVC framework?**

[GEF Controllers](http://wiki.eclipse.org/GEF_Description#Controllers) tells the mvc controller role is taken from the *EditPart*. It creates the specified objects.
Regarding the [examples](http://wiki.eclipse.org/GEF_Description#Listening_to_the_model) the controller holds view parts, but the mvc pattern tells, that the controller only reacts on user interaction and tells the view, it has to update or what ever.
Concluding on it the following code is wrong, because it is part of *EditPart* and it changes:

```
public void refreshVisuals(){
    IPersonFigure figure = (IPersonFigure)getFigure();
    Person model = (Person)getModel();
    figure.setName(model.getName());
    figure.setSurname(model.getSurname());
}
```

Regarding [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model%E2%80%93view%E2%80%93controller) the view has an observer on the model, so the following sentence from GEF is wrong, isn't it?
The *EditPart* syncs the actual model state to the view and implements the observer.

> In the MVC pattern, the controllers must listen to the changes of the model. In GEF, EditParts are the controllers so they must listen to their model to update the view according to the new state of the model.

So what is correct?

To prevent cross-posting have a look on http://www.eclipse.org/forums/index.php/m/755178/.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The wikipedia states a the start of the article on MVC that " MVC comes in different flavors ([MVC overview](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model%E2%80%93view%E2%80%93controller#Overview)). Sometimes the view can read the model directly and update itself, sometimes this is done by the controller.

The primary concept that MVC provides is decoupling the presentation from the view, which should contain no logic. Changes to the model are executed by the controllers, and changes to the view are caused when the model is changed. But this does not mean that the controller can't be the one who updates the view when the model changes. Someone has to do it, right? I personally think that having the view directly read from the model is not a good practice since it makes them too dependent, and that model and view should be completely separated. This is great when you have to make changes in your model (for example a field is changed from being real to being calculated) - you don't have to change your view (but you may have to change your controller, but this is normally easier).

Hope this clears things up for you.